# jhipster gateway hangs during start up in Microsoft Azure linux

Tags: azure, docker, openshift, jhipster

I'm currently trying to deploy Jhipster registry/mysql/gateway/Microservice to openshift for a testing purpose. Since I'm new to both Openshift and Jhipster, I was not be able to figure out a way to make gateway work. Both my JHipster registry and DB works well and waiting to receive handshake from gateway but gate was not up and get stuck right after the JHipster logo without any useful log. Could anyone pleaase help me to figure out what's wrong with it?

Jhipster has been deployed by using: kompose --file src/main/docker/app.yml --provider openshift up

```
**Gateway params:**
EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry/eureka
JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30
SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry/config
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://htgateway-mysql:3306/htgateway?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod, swagger

**Registry**:
JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=***
SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_NATIVE_SEARCH_LOCATIONS=file:./central-config/localhost-config/
SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_NATIVE_SEARCH_LOCATIONS=file:./central-config/docker-config/
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,native,swagger
SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD=***
```

I'm pretty sure that gateway and microservice was working 3 days ago but it's not working at all lately even I rebuilt all with a brand new linux centos machine in Azure (additonal: docker-compose up also not working properly in linux vm)

JHipster registry:

```
    :: JHipster Registry :: Running Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE ::
:: http://www.jhipster.tech  ::
2018-07-11 01:45:53.070  INFO 7 --- [           main] i.g.j.registry.JHipsterRegistryApp       : The following profiles are active: dev,native,swagger
2018-07-11 01:45:57.231  WARN 7 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-07-11 01:45:59.437  INFO 7 --- [           main] i.g.j.registry.config.WebConfigurer      : Web application configuration, using profiles: dev
2018-07-11 01:45:59.448  INFO 7 --- [           main] i.g.j.registry.config.WebConfigurer      : Web application fully configured
2018-07-11 01:45:59.638 ERROR 7 --- [           main] i.g.j.r.security.jwt.TokenProvider       : WARNING! You are using the default JWT secret token, this **must** be changed in production!
2018-07-11 01:46:02.023  WARN 7 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-07-11 01:46:02.873 DEBUG 7 --- [           main] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerAutoConfiguration  : Starting Swagger
2018-07-11 01:46:02.893 DEBUG 7 --- [           main] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerAutoConfiguration  : Started Swagger in 20 ms
2018-07-11 01:46:04.556  INFO 7 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2018-07-11 01:46:04.556  INFO 7 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2018-07-11 01:46:04.566  INFO 7 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1531273564565 with initial instances count: 0
2018-07-11 01:46:04.710  INFO 7 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-07-11 01:46:04.710  INFO 7 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-07-11 01:46:04.710  INFO 7 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2018-07-11 01:46:04.710  INFO 7 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2018-07-11 01:46:06.080  INFO 7 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-07-11 01:46:06.081  INFO 7 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-07-11 01:46:06.081  INFO 7 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2018-07-11 01:46:06.081  INFO 7 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2018-07-11 01:46:06.456  INFO 7 --- [           main] i.g.j.registry.JHipsterRegistryApp       : Started JHipsterRegistryApp in 16.619 seconds (JVM running for 17.477)
2018-07-11 01:46:06.464  INFO 7 --- [           main] i.g.j.registry.JHipsterRegistryApp       : 
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'jhipster-registry' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:8761 
    External:   http://172.17.0.7:8761 
    Profile(s):     [dev, native, swagger]
----------------------------------------------------------
2018-07-11 01:46:06.465 ERROR 7 --- [           main] i.g.j.registry.JHipsterRegistryApp       : 
----------------------------------------------------------
Your JWT secret key is not configured using Spring Cloud Config, you will not be able to 
use the JHipster Registry dashboards to monitor external applications. 
Please read the documentation at http://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/ 
----------------------------------------------------------
```

DB:

```
Initializing database
2018-07-11T01:18:46.046940Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2018-07-11T01:18:46.292450Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2018-07-11T01:18:46.393396Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 5bc6e58a-84a8-11e8-84b7-0242ac110008.
2018-07-11T01:18:46.401694Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2018-07-11T01:18:46.408709Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2018-07-11T01:18:49.829982Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:49.830017Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:49.830027Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:49.830047Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:49.830054Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:49.830068Z 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:49.830100Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:49.830111Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
Database initialized
Initializing certificates
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
.............................+++
................+++
unable to write 'random state'
writing new private key to 'ca-key.pem'
-----
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
...........................................+++
....+++
unable to write 'random state'
writing new private key to 'server-key.pem'
-----
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
.....................................................+++
................................+++
unable to write 'random state'
writing new private key to 'client-key.pem'
-----
Certificates initialized
MySQL init process in progress...
2018-07-11T01:18:53.373337Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.20) starting as process 90 ...
2018-07-11T01:18:53.377206Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2018-07-11T01:18:53.377227Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-07-11T01:18:53.377231Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-07-11T01:18:53.377235Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-07-11T01:18:53.377239Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-07-11T01:18:53.377243Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-07-11T01:18:53.377553Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-07-11T01:18:53.377689Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-07-11T01:18:53.379951Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-07-11T01:18:53.390423Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-07-11T01:18:53.399872Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2018-07-11T01:18:53.405088Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-07-11T01:18:53.425642Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-07-11T01:18:53.425743Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-07-11T01:18:53.528298Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2018-07-11T01:18:53.529297Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-07-11T01:18:53.529308Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-07-11T01:18:53.529551Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-07-11T01:18:53.579717Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.20 started; log sequence number 2565377
2018-07-11T01:18:53.580033Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-07-11T01:18:53.580711Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-07-11T01:18:53.582675Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180711  1:18:53
2018-07-11T01:18:53.605379Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:53.605423Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:53.605432Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:53.605457Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:53.605463Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:53.605478Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:53.607231Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:53.607244Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:53.617199Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2018-07-11T01:18:53.622678Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.20'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2018-07-11T01:18:53.622700Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check. 
2018-07-11T01:18:53.622703Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2018-07-11T01:18:53.635430Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2018-07-11T01:18:58.105504Z 5 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:58.105532Z 5 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:58.105541Z 5 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:58.105573Z 5 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:58.105580Z 5 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:58.105593Z 5 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:58.105623Z 5 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:58.105633Z 5 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:18:58.121444Z 0 [Note] Giving 1 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2018-07-11T01:18:58.121462Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2018-07-11T01:19:00.121609Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2018-07-11T01:19:00.121639Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2018-07-11T01:19:00.122581Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123328Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123345Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123350Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123353Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123356Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123360Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123363Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123365Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123368Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123371Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123374Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123377Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123380Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123383Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123385Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123388Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123391Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123394Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123397Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123399Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123402Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123405Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123408Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123410Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123413Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123416Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123419Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123421Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123424Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123427Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123430Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123432Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123435Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123438Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123441Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2018-07-11T01:19:00.123486Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2018-07-11T01:19:00.133642Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2018-07-11T01:19:00.233877Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-07-11T01:19:00.234237Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 180711  1:19:00
2018-07-11T01:19:01.681745Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 12156809
2018-07-11T01:19:01.683697Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2018-07-11T01:19:01.683710Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2018-07-11T01:19:01.683718Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2018-07-11T01:19:01.683727Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2018-07-11T01:19:01.683731Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2018-07-11T01:19:01.683735Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2018-07-11T01:19:01.683773Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2018-07-11T01:19:01.683795Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2018-07-11T01:19:01.683930Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2018-07-11T01:19:01.686021Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
2018-07-11T01:19:01.968822Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.20) starting as process 1 ...
2018-07-11T01:19:01.972476Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2018-07-11T01:19:01.972494Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-07-11T01:19:01.972499Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-07-11T01:19:01.972503Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-07-11T01:19:01.972507Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-07-11T01:19:01.972510Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-07-11T01:19:01.972879Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-07-11T01:19:01.973031Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-07-11T01:19:01.975195Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-07-11T01:19:01.985489Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-07-11T01:19:01.988059Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2018-07-11T01:19:02.000190Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.017281Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-07-11T01:19:02.017374Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-07-11T01:19:02.126848Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.127715Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.127726Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.128093Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-07-11T01:19:02.178251Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.20 started; log sequence number 12156809
2018-07-11T01:19:02.178487Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.179702Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-07-11T01:19:02.195570Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180711  1:19:02
2018-07-11T01:19:02.197609Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2018-07-11T01:19:02.198096Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.198133Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2018-07-11T01:19:02.198157Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.233539Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.233601Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.233611Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.233636Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.233642Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.233656Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.236013Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.236031Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-07-11T01:19:02.243545Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2018-07-11T01:19:02.244677Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.20'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2018-07-11T01:19:02.244693Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check. 
2018-07-11T01:19:02.244697Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2018-07-11T01:19:02.261578Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
```

Gateway:

```
The application will start in 30s...
        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝
:: JHipster ߤ㠠:: Running Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech  ::
```

Comment: In my experience, this happens when the gateway either 1) can't connect to eureka or 2) the liquibase changeloglock is locked

Comment: @JonRuddell Thanks for your reply, I'll take a look of that